# Should I put all my common methods and utilities in a namespace or make them global?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have a few utility methods that are used on almost every page and in other classes throught my application (eg - IsValidEmailAddress, IsAlphaNumeric, etc).  Should these be in their own namespace (eg - site.common) or just left global where I don't have to add the using to every page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common practice is to put them in their own namespace and then include the `using`

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a namespace named Utility or something similar - it's cleaner this way.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, you should not just create namespace for your utils function but also for each concept that you have in. This way if you want an util communication method you know to you should go in MyProject.Communication.Utils (Depending on how much function you have).

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor them out into a single project, then reference the dll file in the project where you would like to use them.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding a **using** to each page just put it in the web.config

```
 <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <clear/>
                <add namespace="Site.Common"/>
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but again, only makes it available to pages, not other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I'll put my utility methods in their own namespace/class/project, usually named [MyBase].Utils. Example: MyBase.Utils.DataIntegrity.  The classes & methods are (typically) static, as well.

Make sure to create unit tests for each method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate Utils namespace just to put all commonly used methods and other members.ITs easier and cleaner to maintain

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using extension methods? They're basically a pretty way to make calls to static utilities.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend overriding the page object and add those methods to your override. When calling each page, you should then be able to call each method as though it was part of the page. Just my $.02 worth.

Comment: What if I needed to call those methods in classes besides pages?

Comment: Then state that in your question. "used in almost every page" implies you are only using them within a page object. If you are following good application design principles, you would keep what happens in the Presentation Layer separate from the Business Logic Layer. You might want to review the Decorator Design Pattern and the concept of inheritance and object oriented programming to see what I am talking about. What you are talking about doesn't adhere to good design principles or application development. Just because it works doesn't mean it's right.

Comment: A method like IsValidEmail() might be used in methods in the domain, code behind, BLL, etc.  I will revise my question to be more specific.